# Is there a way to change http request method in netflix zuul routing filter?

Tags: netflix-zuul

I'm trying to trasform http GET method call from legacy api server built with MVC1 pattern to new restful api server without any change of front-end source code using netflix zuul and eureka.

I added zuul pre filter transforming legacy url to restful convention url working after PreDecorationFilter and it works fine.

But now I'm facing problem converting the GET method to proper method like POST, PUT, DELETE by distinguising url so that the requests are properly mapped in spring controller via @GetMapping/@PostMapping/@PutMapping/@DeleteMapping.

I looked into SimpleRoutingFilter that handles HttpClient but
Because of environmental constraint, I have to use eureka service id to route to the new api server and that means I should use RibbonRoutingFilter which is quite complicated to find out a right place to this operation in.

So, is this possible to change http method or make new http request before RibbonRoutingFilter?
If possible can you please suggest where is the right place to do that or some reference?

Many thanks!

======================================================================

Milenko Jevremovic,

Would you please tell me more detail about using Feign?

I defiend @FeignClient like below

```
@PostMapping(value = "{url"}, consumes = "application/json")
ResponseEntity<?> postMethod(@PathVariable("url") String url);
```

and to get query parameters to request body for POST In zuul pre filter,

after transform logic from GET request url to POST new restful url ...

```
byte[] bytes = objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(ctx.get("requestQueryParams"));
ctx.setRequests(new HttpServletRequestWrapper(request) {
  @Override ..getMethod
  @Override ..getContentLength
  @Override ..getConentLengthLong
  @Override
  public ServletInputStream getInputStream() {
    return new ServletInputStreamWrapper(bytes);
  }
}
ResponseEntity<?> response feignClient.post(transformedNewApiUri);
```

and set RequestContext code that you suggested ....

and controller of new api server is like,

```
@PostMapping
ResponseEntity<model> post(@RequestBody req..)
```

It comes to controller fine but when I see the http request in post method of controller,
There is no request body for parameters.

(HttpServleterRequest getInputStream shows empty)

The request data set in zuul pre filter by HttpServletRequestWrapper is
not used in Feign maybe...?
Would you please get me more idea setting request body when changing GET query
to POST constructor for using Feign?

Comment: If you change GET request to POST request in your filter, what will you do with parameters, what is the purpose of POST than?

Comment: Of course when changing GET to POST, I should move parameters to request body like..                       
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uriWithQueryString);

Comment: I guess building RibbonCommandContext and RibbonApacheHttpRequest would be the key to do this.. I'm gonna check on working day. Thank you!

Comment: Instead of '======' say **EDITED** so the people can know you edited the question :)

Comment: You don't need to deal with bytes, just get params like Map<String, List<String>> params = ctx.getRequestQueryParams(); check if it is empty, if not do ctx.setRequestQueryParams(params);

Comment: thanks for your time again.  ctx.setRequestQueryParams();  goes to request body position automatically when it is POST.. I will try your advice including saying EDITED next time :)

Comment: Cool, just don't deal with bytes, it will be done by the framework. Get the query params, create new feign request, set the params and do the request. Don't see the purpose of `ctx.setRequests(...)` either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research did not find any built in solution.

But what comes in my mind you can use [Feign](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#spring-cloud-feign) client in your `Pre` filter, get the response, set the response and return it immediately to client from your `Pre` filter.

You can set `Feign` client url or your service id, like it is explained in the docs, it uses ribbon as well .

Change response in your `run` method like:

```
...
RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
ctx.setResponseStatusCode(your_code);
ctx.setResponseBody(new_body);
ctx.setSendZuulResponse(false);

return null
```

Comment: Thanks for your time! I'll consider your suggestion.

Comment: I added more question about using Feign, please check if possible. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to deal with bytes, just get params like `Map<String, List<String>> params = ctx.getRequestQueryParams();` check if it is empty, if not do `ctx.setRequestQueryParams(params);`

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change method of `HttpServletRequest`, but it's possible to replace request in `RequestContext`. `HttpServletRequestWrapper` appears to be very helpful:

```
static class PostHttpServletRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    public PostHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
    }

    @Override
    public String getMethod() {
        return "POST";
    }
}
```

So method `run` can be rewritten as following:

```
@Override
public Object run() {
    RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();

    HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();
    HttpServletRequest requestWrapper = new PostHttpServletRequest(request);
    ctx.setRequest(requestWrapper);

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Yes I solved it by using wrapper you suggested. Thanks for the reply it's been a long time though.